# php: getting a cookie value and adding by one

Tags: php, cookies

```
<?php
 $cwd = getcwd();
 $dir = 'onlytest';
 // get file names from logos directory
 $files = scandir($dir);
 // count total files in directory
 $totalFiles = count($files) - 1;
 // loop through file names and output the images
 $desc = $files;
 echo 'Hello '.($_COOKIE['number']!='' ? $_COOKIE['number'] : '2'); // number of cookie!
 for ($i = (10 * $_COOKIE['number']) - 18; $i <= 10 * $_COOKIE['number']; $i++) 
 {
    $text = substr($desc[$i],0,20).'...';
    $filepath = $dir . "/" . $files[$i];
    echo '<img src="' . $filepath . '" target="_blank" width="25%" height="33%"           />';    
    echo "<a href='$filepath' target='_blank'>$text</a>";
 }
 echo "</br>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doSomething() 
  {
     $.get("opentext.php");
     return false;
  }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="doSomething();">'next 20 pictures'</a>
```

My other file opentext.php is like this!

```
<?php
$number = ($_COOKIE['number'] + 1);
setcookie('number',$number,time() + (86400 * 1)); // 86400 = 1 day cookie
?>
```

I'm trying to take the value of cookie and add + 1, as you can see i want to take the 20 first pictures in folder and then i want to change the cookie when clicking the link below using javascript onclick function, it redirects me to the php file that adds + 1 to the cookie and gives the next 20 pictures, i have been doing this for hours and i just can't seem to get myself to find a solution.

Comment: It is not safe to add integers to cookie values. Cookie values can be modified by the client and can therefore be anything. You need to check that the value is a number before adding anything to it. Also, you are using `$_COOKIE['number']` without checking that it even exists. There are a lot of things that can go wrong with your code.

Comment: echo 'Hello '.($_COOKIE['number']!='' ? $_COOKIE['number'] : '2'); it tells if the value is not set.. set the value to 2.. also if the user modify is not a problem because im using the cookie to show the next 20 pictures on site and when the user get back to site it rememeber his position

Comment: No, it just checks if it does not equal an empty string. You need to `if (isset($_COOKIE['number'])){ ... }` to make sure that the index exists. Your example will generate warnings if the cookie is not set.

Comment: so you mean     if (isset($_COOKIE[]'number'])){ $number = ($_COOKIE['number'] + 1)} else {setcookie('number',2,time() + (86400 * 1));  }